# github pages custom domain

Tags: dns, github-pages

I am very new to making a personal page.

I want to set up a custom domain for my github pages.
I have a account at an apache server with a url like 'server/~username', and I would like this address to redirect to my github pages, and this address to appear for my github pages.

I followed the instruction on github help page, and after adding CNAME file containing 'server/~username'
I got Bad CNAME failure.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNAME DNS records don't allow for anything other than pointing sub-domains at places (the `server` part). The `~username` part is not part of the domain and so can't be added to a `CNAME` record.

I'm pretty sure that what you want to do is not possible.

edit: If you're in full control of the domain, you could create a sub-domain and point that at github, so rather than `example.com/~username`, you could have `username.example.com`. That would work.

Comment: I see.. there's a difference between a URL and a subdomain. Thanks!